# Atributte models.TextField() error "OperationalError at /"

Tags: python, django

so im new in Django and im triyng to setup a simple blog.
[Here](https://github.com/tamercuba/my-first-blog) u can check all files.
So my problem is: when I run the Django server and try to view my site (the template is available [here](https://github.com/tamercuba/my-first-blog/blob/master/blog/templates/blog/post_list.html) ) i get [this](https://ibb.co/BV3fqMT) error message that is apparently related to `models.TextField()` attribute in my [post](https://github.com/tamercuba/my-first-blog/blob/master/blog/models.py) model.
Could someone help me solve this error? Thank you very much.

Comment: You have changed your model by adding a column. Therefore you have to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` to create the migration and add the column to the database.

Comment: Have you made `migrations`?

Comment: Try doing `python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate` seems like you added a new column text into your Posts model but you haven't done a migration.

Comment: Please edit the question to contain minimal excerpts of the the relevant things. E.g. the error message. The question won't be helpful, once the links die.

Comment: The error was too large, and I as a Django beginner couldnt tell wich of the most important parts of the error message, so i posted a printscreen of the error, thats wrong ? I cant understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you change your model/s in Django, you have to make use of the commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

This would ensure that your model changes will be reflected on your database. Example, you added a new field called text into your Posts model. In order for text to reflect on your database you have to run these two commands.

More on [Django's Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/)

Answer (score 0):

When you change your models you need to run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```